# How to find member by username?

Tags: node.js, discord.js

Discord.js 13.6.0 | Node.js 16.14.2

I want to find member by username, same as in bot `UnbelievaBoat` (https://i.stack.imgur.com/WNPv5.png)

Example: username is WorldGod

Type e.g. `?userinfo worl` or `?userinfo WORLD` and bot find member WorldGod

Code example:

```
const arg = args[0] or const arg = args.join(" ")

let member = message.guild.members.cache.filter(member => member.user.username.includes(arg))[0]

message.reply(`${member.id}`) or message.reply(`${member.user.id}`)
```

TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'id')

TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'user')

Comment: I think, I answered it before.

Comment: stackoverflow closed question so i created new with more info

Comment: Use `find()` instead of filter, also your errors occure because `member` is returning undefined

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How find user by not full username?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72250210/how-find-user-by-not-full-username)

Comment: @Elitezen `find()` also don't work, so how does make that member is returning e.g. id?

Comment: @ZsoltMeszaros nope

Comment: What debugging have you done, have you checked the value of `arg`?  Have you tried fetching members instead of checking only the cached ones? I'd also recommend checking if `member` is undefined before trying to use it.

Comment: @Elitezen Yes. Yes. Okey

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the `.includes()` function returns a boolean so what you want to do is create a function based on that boolean.
this is the new code i made for you.

```js
// make members an array
let members = []
message.guild.members.cache.filter(mems => {
  // if users username includes the arg
  mems.user.username.includes(arg) ? 
  members.push(mems.user) // if so it pushes user into array 
  : null // else null
})

// this will send the user's name and id
message.reply(`${members[0].username} ${members[0].id}`)
```

this creates an array for members, then filters users of the guild and if the username includes the argument it will add the user to the array.

After it pushes the user you can access that user however you want... you can get its avatarURL, tag, id, username, etc...

If you want to eventually make it so you list all the options this will work fine because they will all be in the members array, and very easy to map.

Comment: It works, but it doesn't work the way I want it to.
I want it to work if you write in the lowercase but the username has something with a capital letter it still be able to find this person.
Sorry for my eng

Comment: Never mind, I did it myself. Thx for help